# IndexPathForRow(at : point) returns 0 every time

Tags: ios, swift, tableview, indexpath

I have a tableview in a row of another tableview. In the cellforRowat indexPath of my inner table view I want to be able to get the indexpath of the out tableview.

I tried :

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    if let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Answer") as? MCAnswerCell
    {
        if let index = self.tableView?.indexPath(for: self){
            // self is a custom cell used in the outer tableview
        }
    }
}
```

But that returns nil for the rows which aren't on screen. So then I was going to try to use the following:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    if let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Answer") as? MCAnswerCell
    {
        if let index = self.tableView?.indexPathForRow(at: cell.center){
            //returns 0 every time
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: do you have a tableview within each cell, or is it just the one cell

Comment: what you want to do ?

Comment: why you want index in cellForRowAtIndexPath ....instead of use IndexPath.row .

Comment: the easiest and most efficient way to group cells would be to create multiple sections. Then you would access the section by indexPath.section.

Comment: @A.Zaima there is one type of cell which has a tableview. There are many other types but depending on the data source, there could be multiple rows with that type i.e multiple cells with a tableview

Comment: In that case create an optional variable in your custom UiTableViewCell class of your inner cells. When the cell is supposed to have the table, allocate the indexPath to that variable. When reading from the cells of the inner table, simply read the value of your variable

Comment: @KKRocks I need the index of the outer cell because I have to pass this into a method which checks a value in the outer tableview datasource and returns a bool for whether or not to set the on property of my switch which is in the inner cell.

Comment: @Zaima Your suggestion helped me figure it out, thanks a mil!